# fetching data from adjusted checkbox into codeigniter controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web-deployment-project

So I have a page where users can edit their profile. There users first get data fetched from my database so for example one of the checkboxes is checked. Then I want the users to be able to update their checkboxes but for some reason the "post" method doesn't pass the right data.
My view:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>index.php/profile/update/<?php echo $user['patient_id']; ?>">
    <div>
<?php 
    if($user['sport_ban']){
        $checked = "checked";
    }else{
        $checked = "";  
    }
    echo "Sport ban: "."<input type='checkbox' name='sport_ban'
                        value='".$user['sport_ban']."'".$checked.">";
 ?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Aanpassingen opslaan" name="submit">
</form>
```

my controller:

```
$gele_kaart = $this->input->post('gele_kaart');
$sport_ban = $this->input->post('sport_ban');
```

Comment: So what data DOES the post pass

Comment: You might like to put a space between the end of the `value` tag and  the checked like `value='".$user['sport_ban']."' ".$checked.">";`

Comment: Or even use the automatic variable expansion in double quotes literals and do `value='$user[sport_ban]' $checked>";`

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, i don't exactly know what the post passes. It passes  if i let the checkbox as it is when it is one.

Comment: I was thinking it might have something to do with the fact that the checkbox has an attribute $checked on loading? But i don't see any other way to actually check the checkbox